# Uncommon recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given that $c_1,c_2,c_3,...$ are real numbers such that $c_1=c_2=c_3=...=c_{2024}=2$ and
$$
c_n=\frac{2025+c_1c_2c_3...c_{n-1}}{1+c_{n-1}+c_{n-1}c_{n-2}+...+c_{n-1}c_{n-2}...c_{n-2024}}
$$
holds for all positive integers $n\geq 2025$.

Find the value of
$$
A=\left \lfloor{B}\right \rfloor=\left \lfloor{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{c_n}}\right \rfloor
$$
(It can be proved that $B$ is convergence series.)

The answer is $1015$.

I think the idea behind this problem is to show that
$$
\frac{1}{c_n}=2^{2026-n}-\delta_n
$$
$\forall n \in\mathbb{N}$ and $\delta_n\ll 1$ but I don't know how :(

Comment: Are all the numbers equal to 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
&\iff c_n+c_nc_{n-1}+...+c_nc_{n-1}...c_{n-2024} = 2025 + c_1c_2...c_{n-1} \\
&\iff \frac{1}{c_{n-1}c_{n-2}...c_1} +\frac{1}{c_{n-2}...c_1} +..+\frac{1}{c_{n-2025}...c_1} = \frac{2025}{c_1...c_n} + \frac{1}{c_n} \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
Denote
$$f(n)=\cases{\frac{1}{c_1...c_n} &if $n\ge1$\\1 &if $n=0$}$$
Then
$$(1) \iff \frac{1}{c_n} = -2025f(n) +\sum_{i=n-2025}^{n-1}f(i) \hspace{1cm} \forall n\ge 2025$$
We deduce then^
$$\begin{align}
 B &= \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{c_n} \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{2024} \frac{1}{c_n} +\sum_{n=2025}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{c_n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{2024} \frac{1}{c_n} -2025\sum_{n=2025}^{+\infty} f(n)+\underbrace{\sum_{n=2025}^{+\infty} \sum_{i=n-2025}^{n-1}f(i)}_{=\sum_{i=0}^{2024}(i+1)f(i) + 2025\sum_{n=2025}^{+\infty}f(i)} \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{2024} \frac{1}{c_n} + \sum_{i=0}^{2024}(i+1)f(i)\\
&=2024\cdot \frac{1}{2}  +\sum_{i=0}^{2024}(i+1)\frac{1}{2^i}\\
&= 1012 +  \frac{1-2\cdot 2 + 2^{2024+2} -2023}{2^{2024}}\\
&= 1012 + 4 - \frac{2027}{2^{2024}}\tag{2}
\end{align}$$

From $(2)$, it's easy to deduce that
$$A=\left \lfloor{B}\right \rfloor  = 1012 + 3 = 1015$$

Comment: Thank you for your solution! It’s not the way I expeted but not too hard to understand :)

Comment: @alphaptcx You're welcome!

Comment: After I carefully read the solution, there is 1 thing I want to ask. Why can we know that$ f(0)=1$?

Comment: @alphaptcx $f(0) = 1$ is just a convention. In fact, the function $f(n) = \sum_{c_1 ... c_n}$ is well defined only for $n \ge n$. And for the sake of notation simplicity, I define $f(0) =1$ for the case $n  = 0$.

Comment: In the solution there is a transformation from $f(i)$ to $\frac{1}{2^i}$ but I understand that it is valid only when $i=1,2,3,…,2024$, so the value of $f(0)$ is sensitive to the value of $B$.

Comment: @alphaptcx In fact, let $f(0) = 1$ is a trick for simplifying the notation. If we did not use this trick, we could write differently the solution, for example
$$\sum_{n=2025}^{+\infty} \sum_{i=n-2025}^{n-1}f(i) = \color{red}1 +  \sum_{n=2025}^{+\infty} \sum_{i=n-2025+\color{red}1}^{n-1}f(i)=...$$
But the solution will be more lengthy.

Comment: Can we let $f(0)=a$ such that $a$ is not $1$?

Comment: @alphaptcx No, we can’t. Either we do the trick as I did, either we write a lengthy solution as in the 6th comment.